Problema tratando de eliminar duplicados
Quiero crear un código en Google BigQuery el cuál me ayude a sacar duplicados de mi tabla, yo hice el siguiente código de consulta:
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `tabla_original` AS
WITH RankedRows AS (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY orderId ORDER BY creationDate) AS rn
  FROM `tabla_original`
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(rn)
FROM RankedRows
WHERE rn = 1;

Pero me señala en siguiente error:
Column name rn is ambiguous at [9:7]

No entiendo cómo a BigQuery le parece ambiguo ese nombre de columna la verdad. Y obviamente intenté usar Chat-GPT pero no ayuda a responder mi problema

Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. La pregunta luce incompleta. ¿cuál es "ese nombre de columna"? Sugiero que le des clic en [edit] y coloques el texto del mensaje de error completo en tu pregunta. Un saludo.

Claramente dice "rn" como nombre de la columna. Que sale del la parte del "AS" de la subconsulta RankedRows

Qué pasa si pones RankedRows.rn? Lo que le parezca ambiguo debiera resolverse así.

Muchas gracias por querer ayudarme, ya di con la respuesta. El problema ocurrió así: Ese código al principio no tenía la cláusula EXCEPT y yo lo ejecuté, eso terminó eliminando los duplicados pero creando la columna "rn" dentro de mi tabla.
Entonces a la hora de que BigQuery lo evaluara antes de la ejecución daba ese error porque la consulta iba a tener conflicto con la columna "rn" ya existente en la tabla. Lo que hice fue rehacer la tabla sin esa columna y cerciorarme de que se use el EXCEPT y más nunca me dio ese error. Cómo que BigQuery no tenía forma de explicar bien lo que sucedía.

Y por eso se evita usar el asterisco en el select.
